# how to get iframe in window of sencha extjs?

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, camtasia

i have a test.html from Camtasia with video inside.
i want call it in sencha extjs window from index.html.
it should be called as iframe, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Ext.Window({
    title : "iframe",
    width : 300,
    height: 300,
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [{
        xtype : "component",
        autoEl : {
            tag : "iframe",
            src : "path\test.html"
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

Comment: is src:"path"  path to the html with iframe??

Comment: It is the path to your html file.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [ux Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame) shipped with ExtJS. I recommend to use this. You may also find [this thread helpful](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71961)